# Pass a Struct<'a>::method as a `for<'a> Fn(&Foo<'a>)` for use in a closure

Tags: rust, closures, borrow-checker

In my tests I had a helper function that runs a given method on differently configured objects, with a simplified version looking like this:

```rust
fn run_method<F>(f: F)
where
    F: Fn(&Foo),
{
    let to_test = vec![0i32];
    to_test
        .iter()
        .map(|param| {
            let foo = Foo(*param);
            f(&foo);
        })
        .for_each(drop);
}

// run_method(Foo::run);
```

This worked fine until I added references to the tested struct, making it "lifetime-annotated" (for lack of a proper term, I mean `Foo<'a>`).

Now I get an error indicating, I think, that Rust doesn't want to accept a `Foo::method` as a function that can be used with any given lifetime (i.e. `F: for<'a> Fn(&Foo<'a>)`), as required by the closure:

```
error[E0631]: type mismatch in function arguments
--> src/main.rs:54:5
   |
3  |     fn run(&self) {
   |     ------------- found signature of `for<'r> fn(&'r Foo<'_>) -> _`
...
54 |     run_method(Foo::run);
   |     ^^^^^^^^^^ expected signature of `for<'r, 's> fn(&'r Foo<'s>) -> _`
   |
note: required by `run_method`
--> src/main.rs:44:1
   |
44 | fn run_method<F>(f: F) where F: Fn(&Foo) {
   | ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^

error[E0271]: type mismatch resolving `for<'r, 's> <for<'t0> fn(&'t0 Foo<'_>) {Foo::<'_>::run} as std::ops::FnOnce<(&'r Foo<'s>,)>>::Output == ()`
--> src/main.rs:54:5
   |
54 |     run_method(Foo::run);
   |     ^^^^^^^^^^ expected bound lifetime parameter, found concrete lifetime
|
note: required by `run_method`
--> src/main.rs:44:1
   |
44 | fn run_method<F>(f: F) where F: Fn(&Foo) {
   | ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
```

I can work around the problem by avoiding closures (though I don't really understand how `'a` gets constrained to be local to `run_method` - isn't the lifetime parameter supposed to be chosen by the caller?):

```rust
fn run_method<'a, F>(f: F)
where
    F: Fn(&Foo<'a>),
{
    let to_test = vec![&0i32];
    for param in to_test {
        let foo = Foo(param);
        f(&foo);
    }
}
```

Can I fix this without rewriting? If not - is there a reason why this shouldn't work?

Complete code:

```rust
struct Foo<'a>(&'a i32);
impl<'a> Foo<'a> {
    fn run(&self) {
        println!("Hello {}", self.0);
    }
}

fn run_method<F>(f: F)
where
    F: Fn(&Foo),
{
    //same as  F: for<'a> Fn(&Foo<'a>) {
    let to_test = vec![0i32];
    to_test
        .iter()
        .map(|param| {
            let foo = Foo(param);
            f(&foo);
        })
        .for_each(drop);
}

fn main() {
    run_method(Foo::run);
}

// This works:
// fn run_method<'a, F>(f: F)
// where
//     F: Fn(&Foo<'a>),
// {
//     let to_test = vec![&0i32];
//     for param in to_test {
//         let foo = Foo(param);
//         f(&foo);
//     }
// }

// The lifetime-less version:
// struct Foo(i32);
// impl Foo {
//     fn run(&self) {
//         println!("Hello {}", self.0);
//     }
// }
// 
// fn run_parser_method<F>(f: F)
// where
//     F: Fn(&Foo),
// {
//     let to_test = vec![0i32];
//     to_test
//         .iter()
//         .map(|param| {
//             let foo = Foo(*param);
//             f(&foo);
//         })
//         .for_each(drop);
// }
// 
// fn main() {
//     run_parser_method(Foo::run);
// }
```

[playground](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=nightly&mode=debug&edition=2018&gist=d8900a0f1aa7d39a5cad9f7b3fb9ae2d)

An overview of other questions about the same error code:

- [Expected bound lifetime parameter, found concrete lifetime](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32194367/expected-bound-lifetime-parameter-found-concrete-lifetime/32194553#32194553) is about mismatch between trait definition and implementation (`trait { fn handle<'a>(); }` vs `impl<'a> { fn handle() {} })`
- [Function references: expected bound lifetime parameter , found concrete lifetime [E0271]](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39395813/function-references-expected-bound-lifetime-parameter-found-concrete-lifetime) as well as [Expected bound lifetime parameter, found concrete lifetime [E0271]](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31362206/expected-bound-lifetime-parameter-found-concrete-lifetime-e0271) is about a closure `|args| {...}` without explicit type annotations (`|args: &[&str]|`) not being accepted as a `Fn(&[&str]) -> ()`; the answers don't explain why (the latter hints that it was not implemented in 2015)
- [Type mismatch "bound lifetime parameter" vs "concrete lifetime" when filling a collection from a closure](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33807396/type-mismatch-bound-lifetime-parameter-vs-concrete-lifetime-when-filling-a-c) is again about a closure without explicit type annotations specifying that it accepts a reference (`let mut insert = |k| seq.insert(k); (1..10).cycle().take_while(insert)`), which masks a more useful "borrowed data cannot be stored outside of its closure" error.

Comment: See also [Expected bound lifetime parameter, found concrete lifetime](https://stackoverflow.com/a/32194553/155423); [Function references: expected bound lifetime parameter , found concrete lifetime \[E0271\]](https://stackoverflow.com/q/39395813/155423); [Expected bound lifetime parameter, found concrete lifetime \[E0271\]](https://stackoverflow.com/q/31362206/155423); [Type mismatch “bound lifetime parameter” vs “concrete lifetime” when filling a collection from a closure](https://stackoverflow.com/q/33807396/155423)

Comment: It would be good if you took the time to show what research you have done *before* asking the question. One possible way that could have occurred is by reading the numerous questions that have been asked about the exact same error message, linking to them, and explaining why they are different.

Comment: @Shepmaster Out of respect for your contributions here, I've added the requested information, though I don't think it was necessary. I wonder what prompted you to make such a comment, though, as it felt unnecesarily harsh. Did this look like a question asked without doing any research? Did you mean that there was another question that answers or at least hints at an answer? (And why remove the formatting, did it make the question harder to read?)

Comment: `run_method(|foo| foo.run());` - that's it

Comment: @Laney that works, thanks! Still unsure if there's anything wrong with passing the method directly ([as clippy insists I do](https://rust-lang.github.io/rust-clippy/master/index.html#redundant_closure)).

Answer (score 1):

> I can work around the problem by avoiding closures (though I don't really understand how 'a gets constrained to be local to run_method - isn't the lifetime parameter supposed to be chosen by the caller?)

It is. But when you rewrite it without closures, you have also put the reference inside the `vec!` invocation, so it is no longer constructed at runtime. Instead, the compiler can infer that `to_test` has type `Vec<&'static i32>`, and as `'static` outlives any caller-chosen lifetime, there's no violation.

This fails to compile as you expect:

```rust
let to_test = vec![0i32];
for param in to_test.iter() {
    let foo = Foo(param);
    f(&foo);
}
```

> is there a reason why this shouldn't work?

Yes, because the type of `run` is constrained by the type of `Foo`. More specifically, you have a lifetime decided by the caller (implicitly, in the type for `Foo`), so you have to construct a `Foo` of *that* lifetime to invoke the given `run` reference on it.

> Can I fix this without rewriting?

That depends.

If all your test values are literals, you can make `'static` references.

If you're able and willing to rewrite `run`, it's possible to make it unconstrained by the type of `Foo`

```rust
impl<'a> Foo<'a> {
    fn run<'s>(_self: &Foo<'s>) {
        println!("Hello {}", _self.0);
    }
}
```

But then it doesn't need to go in an `impl` block at all.

I think the solution provided in the comments is your best bet, because given that you don't care about your concrete `Foo<'a>` type, there's no need to give the method reference for that type.

Comment: Thanks for the `Vec<&'static i32>` pointer! That part makes sense now. I still don't get the "the type of run is constrained by the type of Foo" bit - specifically what's the practical difference between a proper method that's constrained by the lifetime parameter from `impl<'a>` and the not-a-method `fn run<'s>(_self: &Foo<'s>)`, but that gives me something to think about. Would it be wrong to say that the language rules could be changed to allow `run_method(Foo::run)` to compile without causing issues at runtime, and the "run is constrained by the type of Foo" is a design decision?

Comment: The difference is that Foo is a type with some lifetime. `Foo` is only a shorthand for `Foo<'a>` where the compiler can infer `'a` - and the type signature of `run` is dependent on that `'a`, because it uses the `Self` type in the `impl`. I don't know if the language could be changed without breaking something - nothing immediately comes to mind, but because the `impl` has a fixed lifetime, it could always do something unexpected.