# Specifying lifetimes in nom's `named_args` (expected concrete lifetime, found bound)

Tags: rust, lifetime, nom

I'm a Rust beginner, writing a nom parser that can parse lines that are colon-separated `KEY: VALUE`s. I made a base `kv` parser with `named_args` that can parse a key-value pair:

```
named_args!(kv<'a>(key: &'a str)<&'a str, &'a str>,
   do_parse!(
        tag_s!(key) >>
        tag_s!(":") >>
        space0 >>
        value: rest >>
        (value)
   )
);
```

I put the lifetimes in there to please the compiler.

I've made these two parsers from it:

```
named!(name<&str,&str>,
    call!(kv, "NAME")
);
named!(get_dimension<&str, i64>,
    map_res!(call!(kv, "DIMENSION"), str::parse::<i64>)
);
```

To test these, I was writing a generic wrapper, which calls one of these functions with a `KEY: {YOUR_VALUE}` string, and expects `YOUR_VALUE` back:

```
fn test_kv<G: Display + Debug + PartialEq>(
    kvfunc: fn(&str) -> Result<(&str, G), Err<&str>>,
    key: &str,
    value: G,
) {
    assert_eq!(kvfunc(&format!("{}: {}", key, value)), Ok(("", value)));
}
```

This works fine:

```
#[test]
fn test_dimension() {
    test_kv(get_dimension, "DIMENSION", 8)
}
```

But not with the `name` parser:

```
#[test]
fn test_name() {
    test_kv(name, "NAME", "some_name")
}
```

The compiler gives me:

```
71 |     test_kv(name, "NAME", "some_name")
   |             ^^^^ expected concrete lifetime, found bound lifetime parameter
   |
   = note: expected type `for<'r> fn(&'r str) -> std::result::Result<(&'r str, _), nom::Err<&'r str>>`
              found type `for<'r> fn(&'r str) -> std::result::Result<(&'r str, &'r str), nom::Err<&'r str>> {name}`
```

This confuses me. Doesn't  `Result<&str, &str>` fit in `Result<&str, _>`?

Since it works with the `map_res`'d version, I assume that `map_res` returns a different value, maybe with a different lifetime.

I think I may have to change the lifetime definitionss of my `kv` parser, but I'm completely lost as to how/which ones to choose.

Comment: Please review [Pass a Struct<'a>::method as a `for<'a> Fn(&Foo<'a>)` for use in a closure](https://stackoverflow.com/q/56095637/155423) and see if the answer or any of the linked questions/answers addresses your problem.

Comment: Pfff this is hard. I looked at the linked answers but I think I mistitled the question(now corrected), I'm getting E0308, not E0271. I was able to "fix" the issue by adding lifetime annotations to the `test_kv` parameter, but then was getting that my input wasn't living long enough. I think my root issue is having defined the original function as
`named_args!(kv<'a>(key: &'a str)<&'a str, &'a str>`, which makes both the keyword input and the output have the same lifetime, and I don't think it should...
The combination of macros, lifetimes, and passing functions in Rust is above my level.